# Error using EXPECT_NEAR where the output is within the declared tolerance

Tags: c++, visual-studio, googletest

Using the Google Test Framework, I am using the EXPECT_NEAR function to determine whether a test is outputting a value that is acceptable.

The (3) values or parameters that are causing my test to fail are actually within the 1.0% % 0.1% tolerance of the test.

I've simply tried hand calculating the tolerance to see whether or not the parameter has fallen outside of the limit. They prove to be within, where even Google Test Framework acknowledges this, where it still flags a failed test.

```
EXPECT_FALSE(test_errors);
    if (!test_errors)
    {
        ssc_number_t annual_energy;
        ssc_data_get_number(data, "annual_energy", &annual_energy);
        EXPECT_NEAR(annual_energy, -1.83517e7, -1.83517e7 * 
m_error_tolerance_lo) << "Annual Energy";  // choose either 
m_error_tolerance_lo or m_error_tolerance_hi
```

- Above here shows (1) of the (3) parameters that are causing a test to fail.

class CMTcsMoltenSalt : public ::testing::Test{

```
public:

    ssc_data_t data;
    ssc_number_t calculated_value;
    ssc_number_t * calculated_array;
    double m_error_tolerance_hi = 0.01;     // 1.0%
    double m_error_tolerance_lo = 0.001;    // 0.1%

    void SetUp()
    {
        data = ssc_data_create();
        tcsmolten_salt_default(data);
        calculated_array = new ssc_number_t[8760];
    }
    void TearDown() {...
```

* The testing framework declaring the tolerance of the test, where the output falls within an acceptable range.

I'd expect the test to pass, yet something is causing a flag to be raised, where the output values are for some reason, unacceptable.

Below I've copied the flags being raised within the Test Explorer. They should pass, as they are within the tolerance mathematically. Despite this, Google Test Framework is saying how they are causing the error. 
:
Message: 
S_decode ==> Please fix the year: 0 [1950-2050]
S_decode ==> Please fix the day-of-year: 0

## 1 - The difference between annual_energy and -1.83517e7 is 1.5710115097463131, which exceeds -1.83517e7 * m_error_tolerance_lo, where

annual_energy evaluates to -18351701.57101151,
-1.83517e7 evaluates to -18351700, and
-1.83517e7 * m_error_tolerance_lo evaluates to -18351.700000000001.
Annual Energy

## 2 - The difference between capacity_factor and -2.0241 is 3.3119740638909434e-07, which exceeds -2.0241 * m_error_tolerance_lo, where

capacity_factor evaluates to -2.0240996688025934,
-2.0241 evaluates to -2.0240999999999998, and
-2.0241 * m_error_tolerance_lo evaluates to -0.0020241.
Capacity Factor

## 3 - The difference between kwh_per_kw and -177.311 is 0.00013098710715553352, which exceeds -177.311 * m_error_tolerance_lo, where

kwh_per_kw evaluates to -177.31113098710716,
-177.311 evaluates to -177.31100000000001, and
-177.311 * m_error_tolerance_lo evaluates to -0.17731100000000002.
kwh per kw

Comment: what are the numerical values?

Comment: Above I've posted the error flags being produced within the Test Explorer

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md):

> **Nonfatal assertion**
>
> ```
> EXPECT_NEAR(val1, val2, abs_error);
> ```
>
> **Verifies**
>
> the difference between val1 and val2 doesn't exceed the given absolute error

An **absolute** error is positive by definition. I didn't check, but I suspect the implementation is something along the line of

```
abs(val1 - val2) < abs_error
```

Use

```
EXPECT_NEAR(annual_energy, -1.83517e7, 1.83517e7 * m_error_tolerance_lo) << "Annual Energy";
```

or

```
EXPECT_NEAR(annual_energy, -1.83517e7,std::abs( -1.83517e7 * m_error_tolerance_lo)) << "Annual Energy";
```

Comment: ahhh, thank you for the input! The abs_error function with the negative value was definitely the root issue. It passed after implementing this :)

Comment: Any suggestions when the test fails within the tolerance bounds, even when the value is positive? I recently ran into a similar issue as above, enough though the output is positive.